# What does a backslash in front of the delimiter mean in a here document (cat <<\EOF)

Tags: shell-script, shell

I came across the following syntax in a here document not mentioned in `bash`’s man page

```
cat <<\EOF
hello world
EOF
```

The man page only mentions quotes around the delimiter and a `-` in front of it. So what does it mean?

Comment: [Bash's man page](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/bash/bash.1.en.html) says "if _any part_ of 'word' is quoted...", so it's not just about quotes around the terminator word. And for the purposes here, the backslash is a quoting operator, it's listed as such under the QUOTING section: "There are three quoting mechanisms: the escape character, single quotes, and double quotes. [...] A non-quoted backslash (\) is the escape character.". (One could argue the C-quotes `$'...'` should count as a fourth mechanism, but for whatever reason they're not included in that count.)

Comment: I clarified that on the relevant part of [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/170373), but I'm not sure I want to close this as a duplicate just like that.

Comment: oh, thank you for clarifying »quoting«! I only was thinking of double or single quotes. I should update the answer accordingly

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In fact the man page is thorough about this since it reads

> If any part of *word* is quoted

where »quoting« can be any operator of `'`, `"` or `\`.
`\EOF` quotes `E` and serves the same purpose as quoting `WORD` entirely thus preventing parameter expansion in the here document.

```
a="something"
cat <<\EOF
$a
EOF
```

and

```
a="something"
cat <<"EOF"
$a
EOF
```

both will result in

```
$a
```

rather than

```
something
```

as would be the case with

```
cat <<EOF
$a
EOF
```

In fact, since »any part of *WORD* « can be quoted you may even use `<<E\OF`, `<<E"O"F` or `<<EOF""`

Comment: Note that it's quoting any part of the delimiter that triggers that behaviour. Quoting operators include backslash, `'...'`, `"..."` (also `$'...'` / `$"..."` in some shells). So any of `cat << \EOF` (only `E` is quoted), `cat << E\OF`, same as `cat << E'O'F`, even `cat << EOF''` will do. Personally, I tend to use `cat << 'EOF'` where the entirety of `EOF` is quoted, same as `cat << \E\O\F`

Comment: thank you, Stéphane, I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Wait, does double-quoted `"EOF"` also suppress variable expansion? That's slightly unexpected.

Comment: Yes, it does :)